# SQL Pivot - Query Result vertical to horizontal

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

**Issue Description:**

I have a table with currently three rows (as an example). The goal is to have a select that will ultimately bring me employee_id, val_x, val_y whereas x and y depend on month_nr:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  employee_id      NUMBER
 ,month_nr         NUMBER
 ,val              NUMBER
);
```

`insert into test values (5,1,15);`

`insert into test values (15,1,60);`

`insert into test values (5,2,20);`

**Basically the result should look like:**

| Employee ID | Val Seq 1 | Val Seq 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 15 | 20 |
| 15 | 60 | null |

Is a pivot SQL needed for this or are there other elegant ways to solve this request? How would the pivot SQL look like?

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go with a `pivot` unless you happen to need to support really old versions of Oracle.  But you could also do something old-school with conditional aggregation

```
select employee_id,
       max( case when month_nr = 1 then val else null end ) val_1,
       max( case when month_nr = 2 then val else null end ) val_2
  from test
 group by employee_id
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, your "older" solution works perfectly fine. Yet, I will still go for the "pivot" version since I do not have to support older Oracle versions.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test
PIVOT (
  MAX( val )
  FOR month_nr IN (
    1 AS Val_Seq_1,
    2 AS Val_Seq_2
  )
)
ORDER BY employee_id;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> EMPLOYEE_ID | VAL_SEQ_1 | VAL_SEQ_2
> ----------: | --------: | --------:
>           5 |        15 |        20
>          15 |        60 |      null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e1a9c6967b2f6fcd2181a5bd79be1b17)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your perfect answer @MT0! Great response!